# collision in swift 3 sprite kit Xcode 8

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8, collision

I'm having trouble colliding the player with the wall please help!
It's the left wall that's not colliding, i don't know why, i thought it was the gap/scoreNode. I think it's the physics bodies.

```
Faller = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    Faller.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - 400, y: self.frame.height - 300)

    Faller.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: Faller.size)
    Faller.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Faller
    Faller.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall | gapGroup
    Faller.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =  PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall
    Faller.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Faller.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```

Faller is the player

```
let randomSize = CGFloat.random(min: 600, max: self.frame.width / 2 + 156)
        let gap = SKNode()


        gap.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2,  y:  self.frame.height / 4 - 50)
        gap.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:  CGSize(width: 100, height: 2))

        gap.run(moveAndRemove)
        gap.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        gap.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gapGroup
        gap.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = gapGroup
        gap.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = fallerGroup
        gap.name = "gap"
        gap.zPosition = 1







        let rightWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 243, height: 100))
        rightWall.size.width += randomSize

        let leftWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 343, height: 100))
        leftWall.size.width -= (randomSize - 100)




        rightWall.position = CGPoint(x:  self.frame.width / 2 + 400, y: self.frame.height / 4)
        leftWall.position = CGPoint(x:  self.frame.width / 2 - 400, y: self.frame.height / 4)


        leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size)
        leftWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Wall
        leftWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Faller
        leftWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Faller
        leftWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        leftWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        leftWall.name = "lWall"

        self.addChild(leftWall)

        rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size)
        rightWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Wall
        rightWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Faller
        rightWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Faller
        rightWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        rightWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        rightWall.name = "rWall"
        self.addChild(rightWall)





        rightWall.zPosition = 2
        leftWall.zPosition = 2


        self.addChild(gap)
```

And here is the collision function

```
unc didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact){

    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Wall && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Faller ||  firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Faller && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Wall {

        print("collided")

        let endScene = EndScene(size: self.size)
        let transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        endScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
        self.scene!.view?.presentScene(endScene, transition: transition)



        //                touched = true









    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == gapGroup && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Faller || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Faller && secondBody.categoryBitMask == gapGroup {
        print("score working")
        if pause == false {
            score += 1
            if score > highScore {
                highScore = score
            }

        }

        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"

        let HighscoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
        HighscoreDefault.synchronize()


        print(highScore)
        print("fell")
    }
```

}

Comment: Trying removing isDynamic from Faller (or setting false)

Comment: isDynamic needs to be true for nodes where you want collisions to work

Comment: @Nik Sort of - didBeginContact will be called when a dynamic body and a non-dynamic body contact, assuming everything else is OK.

Comment: @Smilez Can you add a screenshot or diagram showing the bodies on the screen etc? Also, how is gapGroup defined? Have you run with showPhysics = true and does everything look ok there? Have you put some print statements at the beginning of didBeginContact to see if it is being called for the situation you are having problems with?

Comment: So I might better understand SO, why did this question get 3 downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Understand, The isDynamic property controls whether a volume based body is affected by collisions to other objects.

Try:

```
leftWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
rightWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```